# Cannot read property of undefined / req.body returns undefined

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to do the most basic POST request in express but my req.body keeps returning undefined, I've googled similar issues but I can't find the solution that would work for me.

The form in HTML:

```
            <form method="POST" class="vote">
                <input type="text" name="test">
                <button type="submit">TEST VOTE</button>
            </form>
```

and in my post.js file

```
const express = require('express');
const app = express();
app.use(express.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));
    app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
        console.log('post to /test');
        var data = req.body.test;
        console.log(data);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: how are you making the request from client side?

Comment: @Yousaf I'm filling a text box in the form and submitting it with a button, the form is at '/test' url

Answer (score 0):

Try using `body-parser` node module which will parse the post data and append it on `request` object so that you can access it.

`body-parser` extract the entire body portion of an incoming request stream and exposes it on `request.body`.

```js
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));

app.post('/test', function (req, res) {
    console.log('post to /test');
    var data = req.body;
    console.log(data);
    //rest of the code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually you didn't set the "action" field in your "form" tag.
You have to set your action field to 
action= "/test"